# Combining & and * operators

Tags: c++, class, reference, linked-list, operators

I've been reading through an implementation of a List (and its node) using classes and I've found a couple things I don't quite understand.
Here's the code in the Node class that I don't understand:

```
    class Node {
      private:
         Data data;
         Node* next;
      public:
         Node*& getNext();
    };

    Node*& Node::getNext()
    {
       return this->next;
    }
```

What is *& exactly? I don't get what kind of variable is returned by that method.

I think I get it now, later on I have these lines (inside class List):

```
Node** node = &first;
node = &(*node)->getNext();
```

Does that mean I'm storing next's address in node*?

Note: Second question was answered in the comments. Thanks for replies.

Comment: It's a reference to a pointer.

Comment: You should always pose two questions when you think returning a reference might be a good idea: 1) Is the thing being returned actually owned by the user of `Node`? 2) Will the reference never outlive the object that it refers to? Usually only consider returning a reference if both answers are yes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a reference to a pointer. It means that the `Node*` the function returns is an alias for `Node::next`.

For example, say you have:

```
Node n;
n.getNext() = NULL;
```

this sets `n.next` to `NULL`.

If the method didn't return by reference

```
Node* Node::getNext()  //no reference
{
   return this->next;
}
```

the same code

```
Node n;
n.getNext() = NULL;
```

wouldn't <del>modify `n.next` - and, in this case, it would remain un-initialized</del> compile because `getNext` returns an `rvalue` here.

Alternatively, returning by reference:

```
Node*& x = n.getNext();
x = new Node;
```

would modify `n.next`, as `x` is a reference to `n.next`.

Comment: -1 `n.getNext() = NULL;` for `Node* Node::getNext()` would not compile. you can't assign to an rvalue.

Comment: I think I get it now. Later on (on class List) I have these lines `Node** node = &first` and `node = &(*node)->getNext();` does that mean I'm storing next's address in node*?

Answer (score 4):

```
Node*& getNext();
```

Returns a reference to a `Node*`.  Why they chose to return a non-const reference to a pointer, which allows for its value to be changed by callers of the function... I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

That means you're returning a pointer by reference. Meaning someone can modify the actual pointer inside a node:

```
Node anode = /* something... */;
anode.getNext() = nullptr;
assert(anode.getNext() == nullptr); // assertion passed!
```

This doesn't look like a situation in which you would use this. Just return the pointer:

```
Node* Node::getNext()
{
   return next;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Compare

```
class Node {
  private:
     Data data;
     Node* next;
  public:
     Node*& getNext();
};

Node*& Node::getNext()
{
   return this->next;
}
```

to

```
class Node {
  private:
     Data data;
  public:
     Node* next;
};
```

These code snippets achieve *almost* the same, but the latter is

- shorter,
- simpler, and
- allows accessing the `next` pointer also on a `const` object.

So, given all that needless complexity and limitation, not to mention Java-isms such as the `Get` prefix and the use of `this->`, you can safely assume that the constructs and even naming that you see in that code, are most probably *not meaningful*, and even with adverse effect  –  as certainly the `GetNext` method has, limiting the access.

Tech details: `&` is C++ speak for "reference", and the most basic explanation of a C++ reference is that it is an **alias** for some object. In C++03 a reference was indistinguishable from the object that it referred to. No matter the C++ version, there is no such thing as a null-reference in valid code.

To really learn about pointers and references you should use a good **C++ textbook**, and not rely on answers in net forums.

The SO **[C++ FAQ book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)** has many good suggestions for textbooks.

Comment: I was gonna downvote, but then I realised returning by reference also breaks encapsulation, so +1.